# How can I revert Jenkins configuration?

Tags: jenkins, configuration

I have mistakenly removed my read rights on Jenkins and would like to revert that. Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the host where jenkins is running you can modify jenkins main config file which usually placed at `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`

You can totally disable authprisation with:

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy$Unsecured"/>
<securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None"/>
```

or just edit specific rights.

Before some changes make a backup of main config file.